# react-router - idiomatic way to place a User component and pass props, and should I use context?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am a react newbie using react-router like this:

**index.tsx**

```ts
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Root />, // Uses <Outlet />.
    children: [
      {
        path: '/login/callback',
        element: <Login />,
      },
      {
        path: '/dashboard',
        element: <Dash />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

### Question

I need to add a new component to hold user information (whether there's a user logged in, and if so, their name and token).

Where would I place it and how would I use it given that:

1. A login callback needs to be handled by `<Login />`, where the user will be set.
2. The current user will be displayed inside the `Root` component. If there is no current user, a login button will be rendered instead.

### What I have considered

```ts
interface User {...}

function UserInfo(): JSX.Element {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<User>({});

    ...
}
```

and have `setUser` be passed as a prop to `<Login />`, while the `<UserInfo />` component would be used inside `<Root />` (eg to provide the user name).

I am wondering how I could accomplish that in a good way.

On the one hand, I think I should lift state up and move the `useState` hook outside of `UserInfo` and into `index.tsx`.

I took a look at the react-router docs but I couldn't find a matching example.

I am not sure using a context would help here, but maybe  could be placed inside `Root`:

```ts
<Container sx={{ mt: 4, mb: 4 }}>
    <UserInfo>
        <div id="detail">
            <Outlet />
        </div>
    </UserInfo>
</Container>
```

Comment: Can you [edit] to clarify what you are trying to do and what any issue is you face? Where is `UserInfo` being rendered? Can you include a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese sure, will do. Please let me know if it is still unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand of your question you are wanting to store and expose out to various routed content a `user` state. If any component ***other than*** `UserInfo` needs this data then lifting state up is about the only viable solution. Promoting it to the `Root` component makes sense since it can reference it ***and*** expose it out to it's sub-ReactTree via the `Outlet` context it is already rendering/providing. Descendent components would use the [`useOutletContext`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-outlet-context) hook to access the provided value.

Example:

```
const Root = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User>({});

  ...

  return (
    <Container sx={{ mt: 4, mb: 4 }}>
      <UserInfo user={user} />
      <div id="detail">
        <Outlet context={{ user, setUser, /* anything else */ }} />
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

```js
interface UserContext {
  user: User;
  setUser: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<User>>;
  // ...anything else
}
```

```
const Login = () => {
  ...

  const { setUser } = useOutletContext<UserContext>();

  ...
};
```

[image: Edit react-router-idiomatic-way-to-place-a-user-component-and-pass-props-and-shoul]

Comment: Thanks, Drew! `OutletContext` was the solution I was looking for. Your complete example allowed me to understand how to pass objects using it.